# How to create an openType extension that propagates to attendees copies?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm working on a project for booking rooms, and we need to use some extended properties.

We've been using singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty, but as I reported in another question that microsoft graph cannot update the value correctly 
([SingleValueExtendedProperty is propagated only when room accept the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117970/singlevalueextendedproperty-is-propagated-only-when-room-accept-the-event))

I tried using graph explorer to create the extension in some specific event:

[image]

When I retrieve this specific event it is Ok, the extended properties are there:
[image]

When I retrieve the room event, the extended property is not there (I have to use postman because of the credentials, although my user has delegate access to this room, I cannot expand the extensions using my credential in graph explorer)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround using the singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty.

I've found out that when you change some relevant information of the event such as Title, Date, etc.. it forces the propagation.
So what I did was to put a space at the end of the event title and if the event has space at the end we remove it. 
Like (using the c# sdk):

```
...
    GraphServiceClient calendarService = await _microsoftAuth.AuthenticateService(calendarConfiguration);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventData.Title) && eventData.Title.EndsWith(' '))
    {
        eventData.Title = eventData.Title.Remove(eventData.Title.Length - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        eventData.Title += " ";
    }

    Event toUpdate = new Event
    {
        Id = eventData.EventId,
        Subject = eventData.Title,
        SingleValueExtendedProperties = EventExtensionsMapper.Map(eventData),
    };

    var updateResult = await calendarService.Users[calendar.Email].Events[toUpdate.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(toUpdate)
...
```